# test the web application of jsf2.2 using owasp

Tags: java, security, jsf-2.2, owasp, penetration-tools

We are going to test a JSF 2.2 application using OWASP ZAP.

But, it can not be performed well: the test can't understand how the takeover of id of `javax.faces.ViewState`. Is it possible to take over the ViewState ID like a JMeter?
We see in JMeter: http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/PerformanceTestingWithJMeter

Comment: did u found the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but this workaround can help someone.

We set the STATE_SAVING_METHOD parameter to **client** in **web.xml** (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24290_01/coh.371/e22620/myfaces.htm#COHCW347)).

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
```

In this way, the state of the view does not expire.
Of course, this is for testing purposes only.

Regards